# What is the motivation behind capping daily reputation points at 200?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

What is the motivation behind capping daily reputation points at 200? Is it because the mods think we should spend *some* time with our kids? And eat. And sleep. And bathe.

And, if it's not clear, this post is meant to be taken lightly. ;)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap (Just a point of clarification: mods are elected on a per-site basis and have no power beyond the site on which they are moderators, and furthermore they are not all-powerful. StackExchange employees are the ones who decide things like "reputation cap" and other site design items, and they also have moderator powers on every site.)

Comment: Thank you. The phone app doesn't Identify potential duplicate questions as does the desktop site.

Comment: I think the limit should be 201.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's one of the measures introduce to prevent large, rapid changes of reputation, which may be caused by external factors. For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54568) got 144 upvotes in the first two days of existence. It's a good one, but the number of votes had to do more with the [question being linked from Y Combinator](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2707) than with the intrinsic qualities of the question and answer. The decision to not awarding 1440 reputation that quickly seems prudent.

Comment: More generally the designers decided there shouldn't be any action you could take on this website in an arbitrary high/fast amount. There are limits on (almost?) everything.

Comment: Might be a good model for the stock market to follow.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There doesn't seem to be a limit on the "favorite" action: I tried clicking the star as fast and for as long as I was able [without risking RSI], no error message.

Comment: @NormalHuman probably because it doesn't matter, no one gets rep, no loses it, no information is gained or lost, therefore nobody cares about somebody rapidly changing there mind.

Comment: @tox123 OTOH, there is a limit on how often you can change your hat during WinterBash.

Comment: @NormalHuman was there? I never noticed, as in a max amount or a speed limit?

Comment: @tox123 [no more than once every 10 seconds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900)